# Importing an aurelia plugin: Unable to find module with ID

Tags: aurelia

I have tried to import 3 different Aurelia plugins unsuccessfully. Each are loaded, but it seems like exported resources within the plugin are not.

For example, when importing [aurelia-simple-tabs](https://github.com/TGMorais/aurelia-simple-tabs) like this:

```
aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-simple-tabs'));
```

The project builds but at runtime I get the error:

```
Unable to find module with ID: aurelia-simple-tabs/simple-tabs
```

So then I try loading this explicitly like this:

```
aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-simple-tabs'))
    .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-simple-tabs/simple-tabs'));
```

and I get a new error:

```
Unable to find module with ID: aurelia-simple-tabs/simple-tab.html
```

I see the same behavior with every other plugin so I do not believe this is a plugin problem. Is there some Aurelia CLI configuration I'm missing?

Comment: the plugin you mentioned should be using PLATFORM.moduleName and is exporting SimpleTabs from his plugin's index but its not. that won't work if you're using webpack.

Answer (score 0):

In `aurelia.json`, `bundles/dependencies` for `vendor-bundle.js` you need entry:

```
{
  "name": "aurelia-simple-tabs",
  "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-simple-tabs/dist/amd",
  "main": "index",
  "resources": [
    "simple-tabs.html",
    "simple-tab.html",
    "simple-tabs.css"
  ]
}
```

And just use it later in any template:

```
<simple-tabs>
    <simple-tab name="Tab 1">tab 1</simple-tab>
    <simple-tab name="Tab 2">tab 2</simple-tab>
    <simple-tab name="Tab 3">tab 3</simple-tab>
</simple-tabs>
```